# How can i open qlikview management console?

Tags: qlikview

I want to uopload my qlikview **qvw** file on **Qlikview management console** but i don't know how to open it on my server. 
Can anyone tell me the steps to open QMC?

Comment: have you looked at any qlik resources??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address of QMC is:

```
http://localhost:4780/qmc/default.htm
```

You upload your qvw to directory folder which is specified in qmc in:
System tab -> QlikView Servers (choose your server) -> Folders tab

Comment: thanx Hubert Dudek.